# Highcharts incorrect pertange calculation

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

My Highcharts Pie Chart is calculating a percentage incorrectly and I've no idea how/why.

These are the values I am passing to it (Spend vs Budget):

`budget: 34319326.40
spent: 10000000.00`

The correct percentage is supposed to be: `29.14%` even though my chart display `22.56%` as spent.

See screenshot here:
[image]

As you can see, my system's calculated percentage is correct but the one calculated by Highcharts is lower and incorrect. Below is how I pass the series data the pie chart:

```
series: [{
   name: 'Brands',
   colorByPoint: true,
   data: [{
       name: 'Budget',
       color: '#1e80c1',
       y: parseFloat( budget )
   }, {
      name: 'Spend',
      color: '#fdc942',
      y: parseFloat( spent )
  }]
}]
```

I was suspecting that maybe my parseFloat is affecting the accuracy though if I do the calculation on firebug console I get the correct result:

[image]

Does anyone know what could be causing this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: check this `console.log(10000000.00/(34319326.40+10000000.00)*100)` it calculate based on total value

Comment: @Deep3015 Thanks a lot I feel very stupid right now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It calculate base on total value

```js
console.log((10000000.00/(34319326.40+10000000.00)*100).toFixed(2))
console.log((34319326.40/(34319326.40+10000000.00)*100).toFixed(2))
```